# How can I edit memory values for Pokemon Yellow to get infinite money with Cheat Engine?

Tags: cheats, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, cheat-engine

I'm currently playing pokemon yellow and I realized that the cheat codes looked like memory addresses, so I put them in Cheat Engine and attached it to my VisualBoyAdvanced emulator. And I got nothing, it couldn't find the address...

[Link to Cheat Codes](http://www.supercheats.com/gameboy/pokemon-yellow-special-pikachu-edition/5380/pokemon-yellow-codes/)

Comment: It's great that your question was answered, and that it was legible to it's intended audience, but I think a little more effort on your part would have produced a quality question that everyone could have understood. I think this is the source of your down votes. Mine for sure at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to use those via Cheat Engine, because as ardaozkal points out, those are memory addresses for a gameshark. Because you are using an emulator, the memory addresses Cheat Engine sees are those of the emulator as a whole.

If you want to use Cheat Engine to cheat in Pokemon Yellow, you can, but you will have to use its search feature to find the right addresses.

The first step is to open the process of the emulator in Cheat Engine. Next, you will need to search for how much money you have. You will pick a scan type of exact value, a value type of "All" (it'll PROBABLY be a 2 byte value, but we can't be sure) and then hit first scan.

In game, change the amount of money you have. Win a trainer battle or buy something. Then enter the new value into cheat engine and hit "Next Scan".
Repeat this until you narrow down the possible addresses to one (it'll be listed up to three times due to us not specifying the size.)

Double click that address, then double click the value in the lower part of the window. Type in whatever new amount of money you want.

One thing to note when using cheat engine to modify games running in an emulator is the concept of endianness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. Cheat engine only handles little endian, whereas some systems/games/emulators use big endian. In those cases you will have to manually convert your values before searching. Gameboy Color was little endian, so you will most likely not have to convert anything.

Answer (score 0):

Those are GameShark codes and can only be entered through the emulator, if your emulator supports it.

Comment: Then how would you go about interpreting them...

Comment: @Nick82285 what do you mean by that? Editing? The emulator should support that if it supports gameshark. Hit the green tick if this answered your question.